# java.lang.IllegalStateException when I set listview adapter after some idle time

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, observer-pattern, illegalstateexception

> Everything works fine until I wait for about 5 to 6 minutes and then again do the same process of add a particular fragment and setting adapter of my ListView and I get this error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Observer android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver@1c5b940e was not registered.
        at android.database.Observable.unregisterObserver(Observable.java:69)
        at android.widget.BaseAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(BaseAdapter.java:42)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onDetachedFromWindow(AbsListView.java:3453)
        at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:14532)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:3133)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:3130)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:3130)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:4497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:4470)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.removeView(ViewGroup.java:4402)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1002)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeFragment(FragmentManager.java:1187)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:798)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:452)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

**What piece of code I called before getting this error is :**

```
  btnWith.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!withActive) {
                btnWith.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6F00"));
                btnDepo.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF8F00"));

                trans = manager.beginTransaction();

                trans.remove(depoFrag);
                trans.add(R.id.placeInMain, withFrag, "Withdrawals Fragment");

                trans.commit();

                depoActive = false;
                withActive = true;

            }
        }
```

**The above code is inside onCreate() of my MainActivity.java which in turn calls this in its onActivityCreated()**

```
 private void updateTheAdapter() {
    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), postList,
            R.layout.balance_row_withdrawal, new String[]{TAG_AMOUNT, TAG_REASON,
            TAG_DONE_AT_TIME, TAG_DONE_AT_DATE,TAG_ID}, new int[]{R.id.tvListAmount, R.id.tvListReason,
            R.id.tvListTime, R.id.tvListDate,R.id.tvIDWithdraw})};
    }
```

> Note : Everything works fine until the phone is left idle for 5 to 6 minutes. Please help me to solve this error which looks like it has something to do with Observer Pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `trans.remove(depoFrag);` once each time you click the button. If you did not `add` it in the meanwhile, then you are trying to remove it twice... Could that would trigger the exception?

Comment: I tried searching for fragment...if it wasnt null then only I removed it. But it cant be the issue because it works untill device is left idle for some time @JMLord

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that the delay could invalidate this hypothesis. However, the problem definitely appears while trying to remove a non-existing view, since `ViewGroup.removeView` is part of the stack trace and `was not registered` is the final error...

Comment: Sorry, let me rectify : the view is there, since the view removal was performed and dispatched (as we can see in the stack trace). However, it is in the ListView that the problem occurs, as if it was not registered properly as a DataSetObserver (whatever that means).